# In-app purchase for OVI like iPhone

Tags: iphone, ovi

Is there something like "in-app purchase" feature of iPhone for OVI store developers?

Answer (score 0):

This was announced for Ovi apps late 2010 by Nokia and last I heard was intended for launch mid 2011. For more details it might be better to head over to http://forum.nokia.com and ask there.